# Fail2Ban: Why Fail2Ban is banning Cloudflare ips, but rules seem not match?

Tags: fail2ban

This is my `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/nginx-custom.conf`

```
[Definition]

badagents = 360Spider|ZmEu|Auto Spider 1.0|zgrab/[0-9]*\.[0-9a-zA-Z]*|Wget\(.*\)|MauiBot.*|AspiegelBot.*|SemrushBot.*|PHP/.*

failregex = ^<HOST>.*/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=phpstorm HTTP/1.1".*$
            ^<HOST>.*/vendor/phpunit*.*$
            ^<HOST>.*function=call_user_func_array.*$
            ^<HOST>.*wp-login.php.*$
            ^<HOST>.*wp-content.*$
            ^<HOST>.*/admin//config.php.*$
            ^<HOST>.*github.com/projectdiscovery/nuclei.*$
            ^<HOST>.*owa*.*$
            ^<HOST>.*mifs*.*$

ignoreregex =
```

This is my /etc/fail2ban/jail.local

```
[DEFAULT]
ignoreip = 127.0.0.1/8 192.168.1.0/24

[nginx-custom]
enabled  = true
logpath  = /var/log/nginx/access.log
action = iptables-multiport[name=nginx-custom, port="http,https", protocol=tcp, bantime=0]
findtime = 86400
bantime  = -1
maxretry = 1

[sshd]
enabled  = true
action   = iptables-ipset-proto6[name=ssh, port=ssh, protocol=tcp, bantime=0]
findtime = 3600
bantime  = -1
maxretry = 3
```

This is an example of the log:

```
188.114.102.58 - - [09/Feb/2021:07:19:16 +0000] "GET /api/annotations?from=1612163956639&to=1612855156639&dashboardId=2 HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "https://www.example.com/d/KUOy7ykRz/domotica-settimanale?orgId=1" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" "ip.of.my.house"
188.114.102.58 - - [09/Feb/2021:07:19:16 +0000] "GET /api/datasources/proxy/1/query?db=homeassistant&q=SELECT%20mean(%22value%22)%20FROM%20%22one_week%22.%22%C2%B0C%22%20WHERE%20(%22entity_id%22%20%3D%20%27congelatore_6_0%27)%20AND%20time%20%3E%3D%20now()%20-%208d%20GROUP%20BY%20time(5m)%20fill(null)%3BSELECT%20mean(%22value%22)%20FROM%20%22one_week%22.%22%C2%B0C%22%20WHERE%20(%22entity_id%22%20%3D%20%27frigorifero_4_0%27)%20AND%20time%20%3E%3D%20now()%20-%208d%20GROUP%20BY%20time(5m)%20fill(null)&epoch=ms HTTP/1.1" 200 15765 "https://www.example.com/d/KUOy7ykRz/domotica-settimanale?orgId=1" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" "ip.of.my.house"
188.114.102.58 - - [09/Feb/2021:07:19:17 +0000] "GET /api/datasources/proxy/1/query?db=homeassistant&q=SELECT%20mean(%22value%22)%20FROM%20%22one_week%22.%22%C2%B0C%22%20WHERE%20(%22entity_id%22%20%3D%20%27bagno_5_0%27)%20AND%20time%20%3E%3D%20now()%20-%208d%20GROUP%20BY%20time(5m)%20fill(null)%3BSELECT%20mean(%22value%22)%20FROM%20%22one_week%22.%22%C2%B0C%22%20WHERE%20(%22entity_id%22%20%3D%20%27camera_2_0%27)%20AND%20time%20%3E%3D%20now()%20-%208d%20GROUP%20BY%20time(5m)%20fill(null)%3BSELECT%20mean(%22value%22)%20FROM%20%22one_week%22.%22%C2%B0C%22%20WHERE%20(%22entity_id%22%20%3D%20%270x00158d00044a1f1f_temperature%27)%20AND%20time%20%3E%3D%20now()%20-%208d%20GROUP%20BY%20time(5m)%20fill(null)%3BSELECT%20mean(%22value%22)%20FROM%20%22one_week%22.%22%C2%B0C%22%20WHERE%20(%22entity_id%22%20%3D%20%27salone_1_0%27)%20AND%20time%20%3E%3D%20now()%20-%208d%20GROUP%20BY%20time(5m)%20fill(null)%3BSELECT%20mean(%22value%22)%20FROM%20%22one_week%22.%22%C2%B0C%22%20WHERE%20(%22entity_id%22%20%3D%20%27studio_7_0%27)%20AND%20time%20%3E%3D%20now()%20-%208d%20GROUP%20BY%20time(5m)%20fill(null)%3BSELECT%20mean(%22value%22)%20FROM%20%22one_week%22.%22%C2%B0C%22%20WHERE%20(%22entity_id%22%20%3D%20%27bagno_ospiti_8_0%27)%20AND%20time%20%3E%3D%20now()%20-%208d%20GROUP%20BY%20time(5m)%20fill(null)%3BSELECT%20mean(%22value%22)%20FROM%20%22one_week%22.%22%C2%B0C%22%20WHERE%20(%22entity_id%22%20%3D%20%27cucina_9_0%27)%20AND%20time%20%3E%3D%20now()%20-%208d%20GROUP%20BY%20time(5m)%20fill(null)%3BSELECT%20mean(%22value%22)%20FROM%20%22one_week%22.%22%C2%B0C%22%20WHERE%20(%22entity_id%22%20%3D%20%27balcone_10_0%27)%20AND%20time%20%3E%3D%20now()%20-%208d%20GROUP%20BY%20time(5m)%20fill(null)&epoch=ms HTTP/1.1" 200 57007 "https://www.example.com/d/KUOy7ykRz/domotica-settimanale?orgId=1" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" "ip.of.my.house"
188.114.102.58 - - [09/Feb/2021:07:19:17 +0000] "GET /api/datasources/proxy/1/query?db=homeassistant&q=SELECT%20mean(%22value%22)%20FROM%20%22one_week%22.%22%25%22%20WHERE%20(%22entity_id%22%20%3D%20%27battery_percentage_myss_camera%27)%20AND%20time%20%3E%3D%20now()%20-%208d%20GROUP%20BY%20time(5m)%20fill(null)%3BSELECT%20mean(%22value%22)%20FROM%20%22one_week%22.%22%25%22%20WHERE%20(%22entity_id%22%20%3D%20%270x00158d00044a1f1f_battery%27)%20AND%20time%20%3E%3D%20now()%20-%208d%20GROUP%20BY%20time(5m)%20fill(null)%3BSELECT%20mean(%22value%22)%20FROM%20%22one_week%22.%22%25%22%20WHERE%20(%22entity_id%22%20%3D%20%27battery_percentage_myss_salone%27)%20AND%20time%20%3E%3D%20now()%20-%208d%20GROUP%20BY%20time(5m)%20fill(null)%3BSELECT%20mean(%22value%22)%20FROM%20%22one_week%22.%22%25%22%20WHERE%20(%22entity_id%22%20%3D%20%27battery_percentage_myss_frigorifero%27)%20AND%20time%20%3E%3D%20now()%20-%208d%20GROUP%20BY%20time(5m)%20fill(null)%3BSELECT%20mean(%22value%22)%20FROM%20%22one_week%22.%22%25%22%20WHERE%20(%22entity_id%22%20%3D%20%27battery_percentage_myss_bagno%27)%20AND%20time%20%3E%3D%20now()%20-%208d%20GROUP%20BY%20time(5m)%20fill(null)%3BSELECT%20mean(%22value%22)%20FROM%20%22one_week%22.%22%25%22%20WHERE%20(%22entity_id%22%20%3D%20%27battery_percentage_myss_congelatore%27)%20AND%20time%20%3E%3D%20now()%20-%208d%20GROUP%20BY%20time(5m)%20fill(null)%3BSELECT%20mean(%22value%22)%20FROM%20%22one_week%22.%22%25%22%20WHERE%20(%22entity_id%22%20%3D%20%27battery_percentage_myss_studio%27)%20AND%20time%20%3E%3D%20now()%20-%208d%20GROUP%20BY%20time(5m)%20fill(null)%3BSELECT%20mean(%22value%22)%20FROM%20%22one_week%22.%22%25%22%20WHERE%20(%22entity_id%22%20%3D%20%27battery_percentage_myss_bagno_ospiti%27)%20AND%20time%20%3E%3D%20now()%20-%208d%20GROUP%20BY%20time(5m)%20fill(null)%3BSELECT%20mean(%22value%22)%20FROM%20%22one_week%22.%22%25%22%20WHERE%20(%22entity_id%22%20%3D%20%27battery_percentage_myss_cucina%27)%20AND%20time%20%3E%3D%20now()%20-%208d%20GROUP%20BY%20time(5m)%20fill(null)%3BSELECT%20mean(%22value%22)%20FROM%20%22one_week%22.%22%25%22%20WHERE%20(%22entity_id%22%20%3D%20%270x00158d00047b5b9c_battery%27)%20AND%20time%20%3E%3D%20now()%20-%208d%20GROUP%20BY%20time(5m)%20fill(null)%3BSELECT%20mean(%22value%22)%20FROM%20%22one_week%22.%22%25%22%20WHERE%20(%22entity_id%22%20%3D%20%270x00158d00032c28fb_battery%27)%20AND%20time%20%3E%3D%20now()%20-%208d%20GROUP%20BY%20time(5m)%20fill(null)%3BSELECT%20mean(%22value%22)%20FROM%20%22one_week%22.%22%25%22%20WHERE%20(%22entity_id%22%20%3D%20%27battery_percentage_myss_balcone%27)%20AND%20time%20%3E%3D%20now()%20-%208d%20GROUP%20BY%20time(5m)%20fill(null)&epoch=ms HTTP/1.1" 200 79394 "https://www.example.com/d/KUOy7ykRz/domotica-settimanale?orgId=1" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36" "ip.of.my.house"
```

Fail2ban log

```
2021-02-09 08:19:16,903 fail2ban.filter         [582]: INFO    [nginx-custom] Found 188.114.102.58 - 2021-02-09 08:19:16
2021-02-09 08:19:17,029 fail2ban.actions        [582]: WARNING [nginx-custom] 188.114.102.58 already banned
2021-02-09 08:19:17,060 fail2ban.filter         [582]: INFO    [nginx-custom] Found 188.114.102.58 - 2021-02-09 08:19:17
2021-02-09 08:19:17,078 fail2ban.filter         [582]: INFO    [nginx-custom] Found 188.114.102.58 - 2021-02-09 08:19:17
2021-02-09 08:19:17,631 fail2ban.actions        [582]: WARNING [nginx-custom] 188.114.102.58 already banned
2021-02-09 08:19:17,631 fail2ban.actions        [582]: WARNING [nginx-custom] 188.114.102.58 already banned
```

Cannot really understand what rule matches...
Thank you

Comment: Have you run `fail2ban-regex ` ? it will show you which lines in the log match the rules

Comment: Gosh... Was "owa" rule... Thank you for putting me in right direction, I missed fail2ban-regex test... :(

Comment: it seems that is it actually just "ow" rule and it matches for example E%3D%20now()%20-%20, the reason is that the star after 'a' makes it optional. so it is 'ow'+ zero on more 'a' letters.

Answer (score 1):

The reason Cloudflare is blocked is because when you use Cloudflare as a proxy, the client requesting the site from your server is the Cloudflare proxys IP address (whois 188.114.102.58 to verify).

You need to restore the clients real IP address by looking at the proxy headers sent from Cloudflare with something like this;

```
set_real_ip_from 188.114.96.0/20; 
real_ip_header CF-Connecting-IP;
```

The above is just a snippet, you should read about it on [Restoring original visitor IP](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170786-Restoring-original-visitor-IPs-logging-visitor-IP-addresses) at Cloudflare. I use a script that pulls the IP's used and places them in /etc/nginx/conf.d/ for automatic inclusion in nginx.

When all of that is done, the nginx access log would instead show the real IP address, not the proxy IP and it wouldn't be blocked by fail2ban.

Comment: Here is the script I use btw: https://gist.github.com/joltcan/be980d8a87d989f7f1f2349f3db993b6